# Removal of Duplicates from payload in mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, anypoint-platform

How to remove duplicate object from payload.
My requirement is I have a websocket connector which provides payload (a object) every second or sometimes after few hours,we will be receiving messages, In those few entries we will be duplicate records. How to remove duplicate records from payload which we are receiving in different period of time.
example:
At 10:30 AM IST
{
"EmpName":"Sonam",
"message":"Incorrect username or password."}
At 10:35 AM IST
{
"EmpName":"Bulbul",
"message":"Valid"}
At 10:40 AM IST
{
"EmpName":"Bulbul",
"message":"Valid"}
I need to filter and keep only 10:30 and 10:35 AM IST messages.
Please help me how can I achieve this.

Comment: On what criteria are you defining two payloads as Duplicates? on `EmpName`?

Answer (score 1):

If its Mule4 , then you can make use of Idempotent Message Validator. Refer [this](https://vanchiv.com/how-to-use-idempotent-message-validator-in-mule/) for a sample execution.

If it happens to be Mule3, you can make use of an [Idempotent Filter](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/idempotent-filter) and achieve the desired result.

Comment: The Websockets connector only supports Mule 4.